# JavaScript / jQuery escape special chars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to escape a String with special characters and i dont know how to do that.

The  String var value is set by an Input field, so the user can write any special character as he wants, even the ones that i dont know and i could break the syntax...so instead of escape char by char, i want to know what's the better method to accomplish this.

This is my example code:

```
string = '-|{}?" Hello \$#^*&@)(~';

newHTML= '<span class="color-red"><b>'+string+'</b></span>';

$('#my-div').append(newHTML);
```

But i get a syntax error.I want to escape all special characters... as you can see this code detector also is not working when i use ' in the string

Comment: What is the syntax error you're getting? You can escape characters in javascript by using the `\\` character

Comment: Just use the built in text() method in jquery this encodes the string before adding it to an element. In my answer I used that behaviour as a trick to encode the string :D

Comment: Also jquery encodes the quotes already when fetching a value from an input element, otherwise jquery would already error by itself when asking to alert a input element value with a quote in it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or easy jQuery trick:

```
string = $("<div></div>").text(string).html();
```

text() encodes the string inside the temporary div and html() fetches the encoded string :)

Answer (score 2):

You used escape character(backslash) `\` in string. You must use escape character before the escape character in order to escape it.

So you must define this character in your string like : `\\`

You see, every special character in c based programming/scripting languages, must be used with escape character. Like newline or return.  `\n  \r`

Comment: Well, it's a string. So javascript does escaping on the fly while getting user input. If he/she wants to escape a specific character one must simply replace or filter characters.

Comment: Yeah I assume $("input").val() is already escaped by jquery itself.